# Chaining observables in javascript with or without merge map

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following functions:

```
  private findPanel(serviceId: string): Observable<Panel> {
    return this.panelService.getActivePanels().pipe(map(activePanels => activePanels.find(panel => panel.serviceId === serviceId)))
  }

  private createPanel(serviceId: string): Observable<Panel> {
   return this.panelService.addActiveFromService(serviceId);
  }
```

I want to chain them the following way:
Get the Panel from findPanel, if it is undefined, call createPanel and get the Panel it returns, I don't know how I would be able to do this though. I read about mergeMap but did't manage to use it, could you help me with this one?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle , yes I did, but didn't manage to modify for my use case

Answer (score 1):

This chain should give you the panel object whether it is found or not. `this.findPanel()` will return undefined if not found, and in that case return a `this.createPanel()` inside `mergeMap` should do the job

```
this.findPanel(someid)
.pipe(mergeMap(found=>found?of(found):this.createPanel(someid)))
```